# Designing my navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

I have this bar created that slides open when clicked. However, i only want it to open when + is clicked. i have the + hyperlinked, but i'm not sure how to make the the slider only respond to the + and bring back the sidebar to normal (right now it is shifted underneath the content div. please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
        <div id="menu-expand">
        <a href="#" class="closed"><span>+</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div id="content"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->

<script>
    $(function() {
    $('#nav').click(function() {
        var leftMargin = ($(this).css('margin-left') === '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px';
        $(this).animate({ 'margin-left' : leftMargin }, 500);
    });
});

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event 'bubbles' up through the DOM, firing on every parent element *unless* you use `ev.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('#nav').click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var leftMargin = ($(this).css('margin-left') === '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px';
    $(this).animate({ 'margin-left' : leftMargin }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I added that, but it doesn't keep my sidebar from sliding down. i'm thinking there's a problem with the CSS because even when i put text inside the nav tags, the bar slides down. Here's the code: #wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav, #content {
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightgreen;
}
#content {
    width: 500px;
    background: lightblue;
}

Comment: By 'nevermind', did you mean 'thanks for taking the time to help me, but...'?